# Web Scraped Table Using Beautiful Soup Python: Organizing Table?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, pycharm

I scraped a table and it works using python beautiful soup. I am just curios if there is a way for me to print the data in a nice organized table with labels using the code I have now?

```
 from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

htmlText = requests.get('https://www.fangraphs.com/teams/mariners/stats').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, 'lxml', )
playerTable = soup.find('div', class_='team-stats-table')
input = input("Would you like to see Batting, Starting Pitching, Relief Pitching, or Fielding Stats? \n")


def BattingStats():
    print("BATTING STATS:")
    print("Player Name: ")
    for tr in playerTable.find_all("tr")[1:55]:
        tds = [td.text for td in tr.select("td")]

        print(tds)



BattingStats()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str.format` to format your output:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlText = requests.get("https://www.fangraphs.com/teams/mariners/stats").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(htmlText, "lxml")
playerTable = soup.find("div", class_="team-stats-table")


def BattingStats():
    headers = [th.text for th in playerTable.find_all("th")]
    fmt_string = " ".join(["{:<25}", *["{:<6}"] * (len(headers) - 1)])

    print(fmt_string.format(*headers))
    for tr in playerTable.find_all("tr")[1:55]:
        tds = [td.text for td in tr.select("td")]
        print(fmt_string.format(*tds))


BattingStats()
```

Prints:

```
Name                      Age    G      PA     HR     SB     BB%    K%     ISO    BABIP  AVG    OBP    SLG    wOBA   wRC+   BsR    Off    Def    WAR   
Mitch Haniger             30     96     414    25     0      6.8%   24.2%  .252   .289   .263   .319   .515   .353   129    0.0    14.7   -7.6   2.1   
Ty France                 26     91     380    9      0      7.1%   16.8%  .147   .314   .276   .355   .423   .341   121    0.4    10.0   -2.9   2.0   
Kyle Seager               33     99     411    19     2      8.8%   25.8%  .206   .247   .217   .290   .423   .306   98     -0.1   -1.2   4.4    1.7   
J.P. Crawford             26     100    410    5      3      8.0%   16.8%  .099   .316   .268   .329   .367   .308   99     -1.7   -2.3   3.1    1.5   
Jake Fraley               26     40     149    7      7      22.1%  25.5%  .202   .286   .237   .409   .439   .374   144    0.3    8.2    -3.4   1.0   
Tom Murphy                30     60     203    8      0      10.8%  33.0%  .176   .272   .205   .294   .381   .296   90     -0.2   -2.6   4.7    0.9   
Dylan Moore               28     76     263    10     15     9.1%   31.6%  .179   .239   .188   .274   .368   .282   81     1.6    -4.4   -0.7   0.4   
Luis Torrens              25     57     203    12     0      8.4%   26.1%  .239   .242   .223   .291   .462   .320   107    -0.2   1.4    -4.7   0.4   
Kyle Lewis                25     36     147    5      2      10.9%  25.2%  .146   .307   .246   .333   .392   .321   108    -0.4   0.9    -2.8   0.3   
Cal Raleigh               24     8      29     1      0      6.9%   37.9%  .185   .200   .148   .207   .333   .234   49     0.2    -1.6   2.0    0.1   
Justin Dunn               25     11     3      0      0      0.0%   66.7%  .333   1.000  .333   .333   .667   .416   172    0.0    0.3    0.4    0.1   
Justus Sheffield          25     15     2      0      0      0.0%   50.0%  .000   1.000  .500   .500   .500   .441   189    0.0    0.2    0.2    0.1   
Dillon Thomas             28     4      9      0      0      0.0%   77.8%  .000   .500   .111   .111   .111   .098   -43    0.5    -1.1   0.9    0.0   
Eric Campbell             34     4      12     0      0      8.3%   8.3%   .000   .300   .273   .333   .273   .278   79     0.2    -0.1   -0.2   0.0   
Hector Santiago           33     12     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Casey Sadler              30     13     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
James Paxton              32     1      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Domingo Tapia             29     2      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Rafael Montero            30     40     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
JT Chargois               30     30     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Paul Sewald               31     31     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Brady Lail                27     2      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Yacksel Rios              28     3      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Keynan Middleton          27     26     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Kendall Graveman          30     30     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Erik Swanson              27     14     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Vinny Nittoli             30     1      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Daniel Zamora             28     4      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Anthony Misiewicz         26     43     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Drew Steckenrider         30     35     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Robert Dugger             25     11     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Yohan Ramirez             26     7      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Will Vest                 26     32     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Ljay Newsome              24     7      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Wyatt Mills               26     8      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Nick Margevicius          25     5      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Aaron Fletcher            25     4      0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Logan Gilbert             24     12     0      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000          0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0   
Chris Flexen              26     18     1      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   -100   0.0    -0.3   0.1    0.0   
Marco Gonzales            29     13     2      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   -100   0.0    -0.5   0.2    0.0   
Darren McCaughan          25     2      2      0      0      0.0%   0.0%   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   -100   0.0    -0.5   0.2    0.0   
Yusei Kikuchi             30     18     2      0      0      0.0%   100.0% .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   .000   -100   0.0    -0.5   0.2    0.0   
Donovan Walton            27     23     69     2      1      5.8%   21.7%  .159   .239   .206   .254   .365   .268   72     0.2    -2.2   -0.5   0.0   
Taylor Trammell           23     51     178    8      2      9.6%   42.1%  .199   .233   .160   .256   .359   .271   74     0.0    -5.7   -0.9   -0.1  
Braden Bishop             27     8      5      0      0      0.0%   40.0%  .000   .500   .250   .250   .250   .220   40     0.1    -0.3   -0.5   -0.1  
Jacob Nottingham          26     10     31     1      0      6.5%   38.7%  .115   .143   .115   .226   .231   .214   35     0.0    -2.5   0.1    -0.1  
Jack Mayfield             30     12     35     0      0      2.9%   28.6%  .029   .250   .176   .200   .206   .181   14     -1.2   -4.9   1.8    -0.2  
Jose Godoy                26     16     40     0      0      7.5%   35.0%  .027   .261   .162   .225   .189   .193   22     -0.4   -4.2   0.3    -0.3  
Jake Bauers               25     33     119    1      1      5.9%   26.1%  .045   .325   .241   .286   .286   .257   64     0.2    -5.0   -2.1   -0.3  
Shed Long Jr.             25     32     113    4      1      7.1%   31.0%  .173   .246   .192   .250   .365   .267   71     -0.9   -4.8   -3.0   -0.4  
Sam Haggerty              27     35     94     2      5      6.4%   29.8%  .105   .250   .186   .247   .291   .241   53     0.0    -5.3   -2.0   -0.4  
Jose Marmolejos           28     31     94     3      0      14.9%  34.0%  .139   .178   .139   .266   .278   .251   60     0.0    -4.5   -3.5   -0.5  
Evan White                25     30     104    2      0      5.8%   29.8%  .093   .188   .144   .202   .237   .198   25     0.5    -8.9   -1.2   -0.7  
Jarred Kelenic            21     33     131    2      3      9.2%   33.6%  .068   .139   .102   .191   .169   .173   8      1.4    -13.3  -2.5   -1.1
```